# If $T ◦ R$ and $T ◦ S$ are disjoint, then so are $R$ and $S$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose $R$ and $S$ are relations from $A$ to $B$ and $T$ is a relation from $B$ to $C$. If $T ◦ R$ and $T ◦ S$ are disjoint, then so are $R$ and $S$.

I am having trouble proving it (and so far, I think the above statement is true). My proof thus far is:

1. $T ◦ R \cap T ◦ S = \emptyset $
2. Then $\forall (a,c)\in A\times C ((a,c) \in T ◦ R \rightarrow (a,c) \notin T ◦ S )$
3. Suppose for contradiction $R \cap S \neq \emptyset$
4. Then $\exists(a,b) \in A \times B ((a,b) \in R \wedge (a,b) \in S) $

I'm not sure how to proceed with the proof by contradiction (not knowing whether the above statement *is* in fact true) since I need a $(b,c) \in T$ to use $2.$

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question if the disjointness condition for $T \circ R$ and $T \circ S$ is for any $T$ or a specific $T$. For the latter case, the statement is not true. For example, take $A=B=C=\{1,2,3\}$ and let
\begin{align*}
R&:=\{(1,1), (2,2)\}\\
S&:=\{(2,2), (3,3)\}\\
T&:=\{(1,1), (3,3)\}
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
T\circ R&=\{(1,1)\}\\
T\circ S&=\{(3,3)\}\\
\end{align*}
So, $T \circ R$ and $T \circ S$ are disjoint, whereas $R \cap S \neq \emptyset$.